# Vimeo API: Getting error "e.data.split is not a function" on attaching listener to vimeo player

Tags: vimeo-api

I am getting this error when I attach listener to 'play' event on a vimeo player after initialising it

```
player = new Vimeo.Player(vimeo_iframe_id);
player.on('play', function() { // gives error e.data.split is not a function
    isVimeoPlaying = true;
});
```

Although the listener does get attached and subsequent play events are captured by it but why did it complain during setup and how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question at vimeo github, https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/issues/191, and seeing Matt Fisher's (@fisherinnovation) reply I realised it was happening due to a listener in my own code for handling PostMessages

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
 var action = e.data.split(':')[0];
...})
```

Fixed it by including check for string type like `var action = typeof e.data === 'string' ? e.data.split(':')[0] : null;`